# Erro ao tentar usar igualdade em estrutura condicional no java

Tags: java, syntax-error

O código abaixo está dando erro na linha `if (sexo = 1){`, alguém pode me explicar por que?

```
int sexo = 0, sexoF = 0, sexoM = 0, bom = 0, ruim = 0;

while (sexo != -1){

    System.out.println("Digite o sexo: ");

    System.out.println("[1] Homem");

    System.out.println("[2] Mulher");

    System.out.println("Digite -1 para sair")

    if (sexo = 1){ 
        ++sexoM;
    } else {
        ++sexoF;
```

Comment: `sexo = 1` está atribuindo o valor 1 na variável. Para comparar, use `sexo == 1`

Comment: muito obrigado! você sabe por que o loop não para quando eu digito -1 na execução?

Comment: Porque vc só está imprimindo mensagens. Para pegar dados que são digitados, vc precisa usar algo que leia esses dados (procure por `java.util.Scanner`, já deve ter vários exemplos no site). Depois vc precisa testar se o que foi digitado é -1 e usar `break` para sair do loop

Comment: valeu cara, entendi, solucionei aqui.